# how to show selected in dropdown in html when values are fetched from php and html cant be written in php

Tags: php, html

I have this code in html -

```
<select name="uyear">

 <option value="0">YEAR</option>
<option value="1980">1980</option>
<option value="1981">1981</option>
<option value="1982">1982</option>
<option value="1983">1983</option>
<option value="1984">1984</option>
<option value="1985">1985</option>
<option value="1986">1986</option>
<option value="1987">1987</option>
<option value="1988">1988</option>
<option value="1989">1989</option>
<option value="1990">1990</option>
<option value="1991">1991</option>
<option value="1992">1992</option>
<option value="1993">1993</option>
<option value="1994">1994</option>
<option value="1995">1995</option>
<option value="1996">1996</option>
<option value="1997">1997</option>
<option value="1998">1998</option>
<option value="1999">1999</option>
<option value="2000">2000</option>
<option value="2001">2001</option>
<option value="2002">2002</option>
<option value="2003">2003</option>
<option value="2004">2004</option>
<option value="2005">2005</option>
<option value="2006">2006</option>
<option value="2007">2007</option>
<option value="2008">2008</option>
<option value="2009">2009</option>
</select>
```

Now i have certain values stored in DB i have to fetch the value from the DB and then show the stored year as selected BUT i cannot write this year drop-down list in php. Now how can i show selected value in the above drop-down WITHOUT writing it in php code??

EDIT : its just one drop down that i have shown here..i have huge numbers of drop down written in html and if i go to change them in php then it will take 3-4 days as there r n numbers of drop down on this page. Thats why i need a solution with which i neednot change the select tag ino php code ans still can show selected as per DB value.

Comment: Why can't you write that in PHP? It looks like a perfect candidate for a for loop.

Comment: i have edited the question plz read there

Comment: The problem is that in order to add `selected` to the HTML, you're going to have to add some PHP to each line. So either way, you're going to have to do a lot of re-writing.

Comment: That said - it might be possible using jquery and AJAX....

Comment: @andrewsi .. I was thinking the same but it would not be pretty and is but a bad hack...

Answer (score 0):

Have PHP write at another place:

```
<body onload="document.getElementsByName('uyear')[0].selectedIndex=$myDearIndex">
```

Comment: i tried this but its showing blank space as selected dont know why?

Comment: and you do have the correct value (0-based) in $myDearIndex ?

Comment: i used this - <body onload="document.getElementsByName('uyear')[0].selectedIndex=<? echo $year;?>"> where $year is the entry fetched from DB. Is this correct ?

Comment: THis is NOT correct. selectedIndex is an index: 0 for the first option, 1 for the second, ... setting it to 2009 will result in the 2010th option being selected ...

Comment: ok so this should be like this - "document.getElementsByName('uyear')[1991].selectedIndex" if i want to select 1991 value. But what is $myDearIndex then? Im sorry a bit confused iam now

Comment: No. If you want 1991, you want the 12th option, as this is zero-based it has the Nr. 11. So: document.getElementsByName('uyear')[0].selectedIndex=11

Comment: ohh then again i'll get stuck here as how will i come to know that php-db-fetched value is at what index of html select tag :(

Answer (score 0):

If PHP is out, you'll have to do something in JavaScript... and you may need to do a value-search to select the correct index.  I submit that it may be as much of a pain doing a function and then scriptlet for each select as it would be just re-writing your select output loops in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
<body onload="setDefaultSelections()">

<script>
function setDefaultSelection(selectName, default) {
    var select = document.getElementsByName(selectName)[0];
    for (i = 0; i < select.length; i++) {
        if (select[i].value == default) {
            select.selectedIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
}
function setDefaultSelections() {
    setDefaultSelection('uyear', '<? $uyear ?>');
    setDefaultSelection('ucountry', '<? $country ?>');
    ...
}
</script>
```